# How to create graphs in Delphi application

Tags: python, delphi, graph

I need to create graphs on the fly about specific process, with some informative texts and colors.

In the Unix world there's Graphviz including 'dot' for layout generation, is there something similar which could be used with Delphi?

I'm using Delphi 2007.

Also Python alternative could be considered, but I'd prefer pure Delphi in this case.

Comment: @HpTerm I mean this kind of graphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Harriv, You can try [WinGraphviz](http://wingraphviz.sourceforge.net/wingraphviz/) wich is a COM Wrapper for [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

check this [link](http://kylecordes.com/2003/11/24/graphviz-delphi/) for more info.

[image]

Comment: Closest thing I need, althought not native solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use SimpleGraph from [DelphiArea](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/simplegraph/).
A have test and use it and it's a great component. Freeware with sources.

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Looks nice, however no automation layout?

Comment: No. It's a pure VCL component. A TCustomControl descendant.

Answer (score 1):

TMS also have a [diagram studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp) and a [workflow studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/workflow.asp)

and a post about the ways to make [it](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=151)

Answer (score 1):

Steema Software has a Delphi VCL TeeChart product that you may find interesting depending on your needs.

[Steema Software TeeChart VCL](http://www.steema.com/teechart/vcl)

I have experimented with the trial version of this. I was able to create some very nice looking graphs. I was also able to use a shape file of the counties in our state to show statistics per county in a 3D view where the counties with the highest values stood out to the user.