# How to show relationships in my application?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I'm developing my MS Access database editor (mdb, accdb) which I will give everyone for free. I've done mostly everything that matters except relationships. The problem for me is how to show relationship(s). I would like to do it like in the real MS Access:

[image]

The thing is, I don't know how would I connect these child windows with a line that is stretching and resizing when one of the windows move etc...

This maybe not a question that can have a direct answer but I'm stuck here and don't know how to show those relationship(s). I'm using C++ Builder XE2.

Comment: How do you interact with Acess? Are you working through OLE automation?

Comment: Long time ago I made a related component for designing queries at runtime with a GUI. Maybe you can find something useful in this code: http://pastebin.com/NDBSCChC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need a library to draw graphs...
Making an answer, for being able to put links in the list (which comments would not allow)

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/extgraph/
- [How to create graphs in Delphi application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252779)
- http://www.torry.net/pages.php?s=88

Comment: Yes! That is something I didn't consider. Thanks.

Comment: You should take into account that if you'll want to interact with those table elements (like move them accross the graph, rename their fields etc.) it may be quite difficult to do that with a pure graph control. I would personally make those tables as draggable custom controls and draw those lines directly on their parent's (e.g. your own container) canvas. Actually, I've made exactly that a few years ago. Unfortunately, I can't share the code.

Comment: I wonder if someone implemented something like DirectX SDK GraphEdit in Delphi...

Comment: @TLama, That crossed my mind. I would definitely like if those would be moving elements...

Comment: @Tracer there are a lot of movable panels, with captions or not, in different libraries and tutorials. JediVCL for example, www.torry.net for example

The difficult thing would not be moving those panels, but optimizing and drawing graph, while thosewires would tend to "entangle" if the user would realyl move the elements hard

Comment: I found TLine component and will try to use it to connect objects like two Listboxes or similiar.